# what parameters to change on oracle database server to meet high (1000 requests/sec) load

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, hikaricp

I have a server running a stored procedure which returns the list of places nearest to a provided lat,long stored in oracle spatial. Currently below are the specs: on amazon ec2 (single vm) we have oracle 11g R2 enterprise with 400 connections, 500 gig hard disk drive,16 cpu vm.

tomcat jdbc pool is set to 50. Want to understand how to size this configuration and scale it. If I run the load tests with more than 500 requests, I start seeing the connection not available error.

How to scale this setup to meet high (1000 requests/sec) load. what parameters to change on  oracle database server / hikariCP connection pool

Comment: Can you provide the exact Oracle error messages?  Without the `ORA-` numbers we can only guess at the problems.  (My best guess is the parameters PROCESSES and SESSIONS need to be increased if they were left at the default.)

Comment: I have done this using the below statements:
alter system set processes=2000 scope=spfile;
alter system set sessions=400 scope=spfile;
error is as below:
HikariPool-0 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms.